# How many times can I refresh the 90-day stay in Taiwan? Can I keep refreshing it with a visa run indefinitely?

Tags: visa-free-entry, taiwan, long-term

As a UK citizen I understand I can spend 90 days visa-free in Taiwan and extend this by a further 90 days, after this can I keep doing visa runs to get additional 90 day stays?

Comment: Why do you want to spend so long in Taiwan? Extension requests can be denied if the purpose of stay is unclear https://www.boca.gov.tw/dl-1941-10818f41fd244cbbbb5de39737fc963a.html

Answer (score 2):

Not really. This is a thing of the 1990s, not the 2020s. This is now very much frowned upon by just every country in the region (except, maybe, the PRC). Staying 90 days, leaving, and coming back the next day is tantamount to living there without a resident visa, not paying taxes, etc.

While this used to be tolerated 30 years ago, it's not today. It shows also in the [tourist visa extension](https://www.roc-taiwan.org/ph_en/post/8583.html#:%7E:text=A%20visitor%20visa%20holder%20who,extension%20up%20to%2015%20days) scheme: you get a measly 15 days, not another full ride – as is the case for instance in Thailand. They do not want you to stay much longer as a tourist. Trying a visa run might get you the "no extension will be granted" stamp too.

Another complication is the visa run itself. Most places around Taiwan will not let you fly to Taiwan on a TPE-somewhere return ticket and no resident visa. If you can't show them either a resident visa or a plane ticket leaving Taiwan, they won't let you board the flight to Taipei. In case you were denied entry in Taiwan they'd be held financially and legally responsible, something airlines do not particularly enjoy.

Even as an older business exec, who can't be suspected at first sight of being a "digital nomad" I was systematically asked for a visa or onward ticket in most of Asia's airports. The most insistent/anally retentive being Japan, South Korea, Taiwan, Vietnam and HK. In places like Thailand, Laos or Myanmar it was kinda random.

Your best bet is to enrol for Chinese classes, and get a student visa. Be sure to attend the classes, Immigration tends to check attendance records.